# iOS SpringBoard doesn't load Notification Service Extension

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I'm sending a regular push notification and expect it to be updated by Notification Service Extension on iOS13. But this doesn't happen and I see the original notification only. Console logs contain:

```
error   11:52:35.116942+1100    SpringBoard [au.com.mybeeper.chatapp] No extension available for bundle
```

The worst part is if I reinstall the app several times this issue disappears and Notification Service Extension starts working as expected. But at any other point after the next app reinstallation, it could start failing again.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 4):

After rebooting the device problem has disappeared. Still not sure what was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the notification service extension to the target like below?

[image]

Comment: Sure, otherwise it wouldn't work after several reinstallations.